# django template convert object to int

Tags: django

I'm trying to run this code in my django template:

```
{% if lawChoice.releveAnnee==law.releveAnnee %}
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '==law.releveAnnee' from 'lawChoice.releveAnnee==law.releveAnnee'
```

I think law.releveAnnee is considered as an object, not as an integer, that's why the comparison fails!

Thanks in advance for your help,

Romain

**EDIT**

Thanks to the answer above: a SPACE is needed BEFORE and AFTER the ==:

```
{% if lawChoice.releveAnnee == law.releveAnnee %}
```

This works! Solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably that's because you need to add a space before and after the `==` operator.

You'd better go for [ifequal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal)

```
{% ifequal lawChoice.releveAnnee law.releveAnnee %}
    ...
{% endifequal %}
```

Comment: It works for one comparison :). But it does not work for {% ifequal lawChoice.releveAnnee law.releveAnnee and ifequal lawChoice.releveMois law.releveMois and ifequal lawChoice.noOrdre law.noOrdre %}. I can use nested ifequal but I'm sure there is an easier solution.

Comment: Try to add a space before and after the == operator.